# Определить какой класс в protected наследовании

Tags: c++, c++11

Помогите найти быстрый метод проверки типа объекта. Было простое наследование **public** и я использовал **dynamic_cast**. Было всё хорошо.

```
class BaseVirtual{};
class A:public BaseVirtual {};
class B:public BaseVirtual {};
bool isA(BaseVirtual * x){
  return dynamic_cast<A*>(x);}
```

Дальше появился класс с **protected** наследованием но **dynamic_cast** отказывается работать, возвращает всегда **nullptr**.

```
class C:protected BaseVirtual {};
bool isC(BaseVirtual * x){
      return dynamic_cast<C*>(x);} // всегда FALSE
```

Когда-то пользовался виртуальными функциями, но отказался для скорости. Переключился на **dynamic_cast**.

```
//--- результат опроса ---
```

Допустим я вернулся на реализацию с помощью виртуальных функций. Представьте, что все классы наследуются в **protected** режиме. Сколько методов нужно определить, если классов например пятьдесят. Поэтому вопрос остаётся прежним: как избавится от виртуальных методов?

```
// g++ -std=c++11 protclas.cpp -o protclas
# include <iostream>
class A{
public:
virtual bool isB(){return false;}  
virtual bool isC(){return false;}
virtual ~A(){}
};

class B:public A{
public:
virtual ~B(){}
virtual bool isB(){return true;}
};

class C:protected A{
public:
virtual ~C(){}
virtual bool isC(){return true;}
};

int main(){
 A * x=reinterpret_cast<A*>( new C);
 A * y=reinterpret_cast<A*>( new B);
 std::cout<<"x=C:(x->isC())="<<(x->isC())<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"y=B:(y->isC())="<<(y->isC())<<std::endl;
 delete y;
 delete x;}
```

Comment: функция `isC` метод класса?

Comment: isC это внешний вопрос

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что виртуальность дала просадку по скорости. dynamic_cast  скорее всего будет где то таким же по скорости. Бенчмарки делали или "одна бабка сказала"?

Comment: еще вопрос: а функция `isA` в таком виде у вас компилируется?

Comment: Сделай isC другом класса С. Вообще что-то странное а архитектуре. Если никто, кроме наследников, не должен знать что С - наследник базового класса, то зачем может понадобиться подобная проверка?

Comment: Реальный код: ...case  ParaLispObject  :: TypeType ::  TypeBIF :
    if  ( dynamic_cast  < PLOBIF  * > ( & x ) ) goto  OK  ;
    symboltypename  = plosbif ; break ;...

Comment: _«Когда-то пользовался виртуальными функциями, но отказался для скорости. Переключился на dynamic_cast.»_ И что, профайлер показал, что решение с `dynamic_cast` работает быстрее?

Comment: Вы бы может хоть немножко объяснили, для чего вам понадобился такой канонический и вдоль-и-поперек изъезженный антипаттерн и пример дичайшего неправильного ООП, как выяснение конкретного типа объекта?

Comment: @AnT : интерпретатор принимает объект универсальный, и от типа объекта выполняет разные действия. Вся прога усеяна данными свитчами и нужно выполнять проверку типа как можно быстрее. Метод **dynamic_cast** лажанул, так-что остался только запасной вариант как виртуальные методы.

Comment: @AlexGlebe: Да, но задача "от типа объекта выполняет разные действия" в общем случае обычно решается через классическое ООП, т.е. через полиморфизм, через виртуальные методы. И это будет работать намного эффективнее, чем `dynamic_cast` и "прога, усеянная свитчами". Что именно в вашей задаче заставило вас пойти по пути `dynamic_cast` и "свитчей" вместо нормального человеческого полиморфизма?

Comment: @AnT : Куча алгоритмов, например бинарные деревья, у которых по указателю может быть узел данных с ссылками налево и направо. По этим указателям может быть другой узел ИЛИ объект nil ИЛИ одинарный объект без ссылок. Проход по дереву с помощью *дичайшего* способа рекурсии никому не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 2):

Отвечая на вторую часть исправленного вопроса:
Не нужно пытаться написать isB/isC ни в виде виртуальных функций, ни в виде внешних функций. В идеале число виртуальных методов базового класса должно соответствовать числу точек использования этого интерфейса. Так вместо

```
case ParaLispObject::TypeType::TypeBIF : 
     if ( dynamic_cast < PLOBIF * > ( & x ) ) goto OK ; 
     symboltypename = plosbif ; break
```

Напишем:

```
class BaseVirtual
{
 public: 
 virtual bool isCompatible( ParaLispObject::TypeType ) { return false; }
 virtual const char* symbolTypeName() { return ""; }
};
// ...
switch( foo ) {
// ... 
case ParaLispObject::TypeType::TypeBIF : 
       if ( x.isCompatible(foo) ) goto OK ; 
      symboltypename = x.symbolTypeName() ; break ;
```

Вероятно, это позволит частично или полностью избавься от switch.

Comment: Хорошая идея по поводу проверки типа, написал `virtual bool  isType  ( Type  t ) { return  t ==  Type::TC ; }`. Всё пашет.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще очень странно, что у вас:

```
bool isC(BaseVirtual * x){
  return dynamic_cast<C*>(x);} // всегда FALSE
```

Хотя при попытке скомпилировать данный код (который конечно не является полным и пришлось вручную добавить конструктор и обнуленную виртуальную функцию) компилятор вполне внятно выдает ошибку:

```
1.cpp:37:22: error: cannot cast 'C' to its protected base class 'BaseVirtual'
    std::cout << isA(&c) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Новый объект C при отправке во внешний мир всегда посылается указателем на `reinterpret_cast<BaseVirtual*>`

Comment: @AlexGlebe тоесть так как у вас невозможно привести автоматически тип от `C` к `BaseVirtual` вы используете `reinterpret_cast`? А потом хотите, чтобы оно приводило обратно к `C` с помощью `dynamic_cast` ? Вам самим не кажется это странным?

Comment: @AlexGlebe я не эксперт, но, ИМХО, из-за того, что у вас предок объявлен как `private` невозможно автоматическое приведение типа, так как указатель на базовый класс просто не видит допустимого приведения

Comment: Не вижу ничего странного, `protected` наследование защищает `public` элементы, они становятся `protected`. Нужно для практических целей. Код от `reinterpret_cast` не становится нерабочим. (Если всё правильно делать.)

Comment: @AlexGlebe `reinterpret_cast` просто интерпретирует данные - он переведет указатель в указатель на что угодно - можешь его использовать вместо dynamic_cast - и у тебя будет всегда `true` даже если это и не тот объект.

Answer (score 0):

Так как `class C:protected BaseVirtual {};`   класс `С` и его наследники используют для своей реализации все  открытые и защищенные члены класса `BaseVirtual`.

Но обьекты типа `С`  могут являються  обьектом типа  `BaseVirtual`
настолько же, насколько любой произвольный тип (`т.е. не могут являются`), и невозможно привести  `BaseVirtual*  в C*`  если это не делается в  функциях этих классов...

Так что

```
  bool isC(BaseVirtual * x){
      return dynamic_cast<C*>(x);}
```

очевидно, что всегда выдаст `false`

Answer (score 0):

Не пользуясь виртуальными функциями можно определить фактический объект в памяти, если объект имеет хоть одну виртуальную функцию. Функция **typeid** возвращает таблицу **type_info**. Можно эти таблицы сравнивать. Если класс без виртуальных функций, то информацию об этом типе.

```
// g++ -std=c++11 protclas2.cpp -o protclas2
# include <iostream>
# include <typeinfo>
class SA{};
class SPuB:public SA{};
class SProC:protected SA{};
class SPriD:private SA{};

class A{
public:
virtual ~A(){}
};

class B:public A{
public:
virtual ~B(){}
};

class C:protected A{
public:
virtual ~C(){}
};

class D:private A{
public:
virtual ~D(){}
};

int main(){
  A * z=reinterpret_cast<A*>( new A);
  A * x=reinterpret_cast<A*>( new C);
  A * y=reinterpret_cast<A*>( new B);
  A * v=reinterpret_cast<A*>( new D);
  SA * sa=reinterpret_cast<SA*>( new SA);
  SA * spub=reinterpret_cast<SA*>( new SPuB);
  SA * sproc=reinterpret_cast<SA*>( new SProC);
  SA * sprid=reinterpret_cast<SA*>( new SPriD);
  if(typeid(*z)==typeid(A))std::cout<<"z==A"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*z)==typeid(B))std::cout<<"z==B"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*z)==typeid(C))std::cout<<"z==C"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*z)==typeid(D))std::cout<<"z==D"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*x)==typeid(A))std::cout<<"x==A"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*x)==typeid(B))std::cout<<"x==B"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*x)==typeid(C))std::cout<<"x==C"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*x)==typeid(D))std::cout<<"x==D"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*y)==typeid(A))std::cout<<"y==A"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*y)==typeid(B))std::cout<<"y==B"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*y)==typeid(C))std::cout<<"y==C"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*y)==typeid(D))std::cout<<"y==D"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*v)==typeid(A))std::cout<<"v==A"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*v)==typeid(B))std::cout<<"v==B"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*v)==typeid(C))std::cout<<"v==C"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*v)==typeid(D))std::cout<<"v==D"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sa)==typeid(SA))std::cout<<"sa==SA"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sa)==typeid(SPuB))std::cout<<"sa==SPuB"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sa)==typeid(SProC))std::cout<<"sa==SProC"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sa)==typeid(SPriD))std::cout<<"sa==SPriD"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*spub)==typeid(SA))std::cout<<"spub==SA"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*spub)==typeid(SPuB))std::cout<<"spub==SPuB"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*spub)==typeid(SProC))std::cout<<"spub==SProC"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*spub)==typeid(SPriD))std::cout<<"spub==SPriD"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sproc)==typeid(SA))std::cout<<"sproc==SA"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sproc)==typeid(SPuB))std::cout<<"sproc==SPuB"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sproc)==typeid(SProC))std::cout<<"sproc==SProC"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sproc)==typeid(SPriD))std::cout<<"sproc==SPriD"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sprid)==typeid(SA))std::cout<<"sprid==SA"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sprid)==typeid(SPuB))std::cout<<"sprid==SPuB"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sprid)==typeid(SProC))std::cout<<"sprid==SProC"<<std::endl;
  if(typeid(*sprid)==typeid(SPriD))std::cout<<"sprid==SPriD"<<std::endl;
  delete  sprid;
  delete  sproc;
  delete  spub;
  delete  sa;
  delete v;
  delete y;
  delete x;
  delete  z;}
```

Данный пример возвращает результат, что все объекты с виртуальными функциями распознаются от любых типов указателей. Простые типы не распознаются, так как у них нет таблиц типа.

```
z==A
x==C
y==B
v==D
sa==SA
spub==SA
sproc==SA
sprid==SA
```

**typeid** всё-таки проиграл виртуальным методам, при сравнении двух типов вызывается **strcmp**. Я в шоке.

```
/usr/include/c++/7/typeinfo:
// Even with the new abi, on systems that support dlopen
// we can run into cases where type_info names aren't merged,
// so we still need to do string comparison.
bool operator==(const type_info& __arg) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT {
  return ((__name == __arg.__name)
      || (__name[0] != '*' &&
      __builtin_strcmp (__name, __arg.__name) == 0)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Английский вариант нашёл самый удачный: без виртуальных вызовов, чтения строк имени класса. Нужна только одна переменная кода типа.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172306/efficient-run-time-type-checking-in-c

```
// g++ -std=c++11 gettype.cpp -o gettype
# include <iostream>
enum Type : uint8_t { TBase , TNumber } ;

class Base {
protected :
  Type t { TBase } ;
public :
  Base(){}
  Base(Type x):t{x}{}
  Type GetType()const{return t;}
} ;

class Number : protected Base {
public:
  Number():Base(TNumber){}
} ;

int main(){
  Number n;
  Base * np = reinterpret_cast < Base * > ( & n ) ;
  std::cout<<"*np = "<<((np->GetType() == TNumber)?"Number":"NotNumber")<<std::endl;
  }
```